# How many trees are there in California you can drive through?

Tags: trees, california

A Recent news event [*(Pioneer Cabin Tree in California felled by storms)*](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-38561877), brought drive through trees to mind.  When I looked at the pictures, I realized it is not the same tree I drove through last time I was in the Redwood Forest.

Searching found some different answers.  [This one by the US forest service](https://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/fsbdev3_058751.pdf) and [this one by a commercial site](http://www.seecalifornia.com/attractions/california-drive-through-trees.html).  Both seem to be subject to some bias, The commercial site lists more, but not sure it is exhaustive.

How many trees **(singular)** are there in California you can drive through, as of January 9, 2017?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a sightseeing question. We've been having a debate on the same and would like to keep this on hold till we have a clear consensus. Please refer [this](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-general-sightseeing-on-topic) meta question for more information.

Answer (score -4):

- Drive thru tree park
- Klamath tour tree thru
- Shrine Drive thru tree
- tunnel log

Can't see many more than that!

Comment: This is essential what I have in the question.  Can you expand on why this is the correct answer, preferably with references?

Comment: You can see for yourself with google that the four I have listed are in fact drive thru trees, but I can not prove there are no other drive thru trees in CA, I can only prove that there are these trees.